# Convert.ToString(...) or Object.ToString() for performance

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Suppose I have a loop which is going to convert an `ArrayList` with 10 million elements, filled with `int`, to an array of `string`. Should I be using `Convert.ToString(...)` or `Object.ToString()`? Is it true that in this case `Convert.ToString(...)` unboxes the elements and decreases the performance?

Comment: If they're in an `ArrayList` they've already been boxed.

Comment: What does the Profiler results say?

Comment: yes, but what is interesting is that Object.ToString() is a virtual method that will be resolved to int.ToString(), so there is no unboxing. But I'm not sure what will happen for Convert.ToString()

Comment: Just tested, for my Corei5 750 2.66 GHz with 10 million elements in ArrayList, it takes about 1.23 seconds for Object.ToString() and about 1.36 seconds for Convert.ToString(...)

Comment: There really won't be a difference. Convert.ToString() is going to take an object ( unless you cast it ) and Object.ToString() does whats obvious. Has I thought a 1/10 of a second is nothing.  If you get away from the horrible ArrayList you will see a huge imporvement more then likely.  Why you would use an Arraylist when your using VS2010 and have GENERICS at you fingertips worries me.

Comment: Yes, I always use List<int>. Using ArrayList would be madness! For this particular example, I'm just trying to understand the behavior of ToString() and Convert.ToString(...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've got an `ArrayList`, any value types will already be boxed. Why are you using `ArrayList` rather than a `List<int>`? The latter will avoid both the execution time cost of boxing and the significant space implications.

After changing to use `List<int>` however, I'd then just call `ToString`. It says exactly what you want to do in a simpler way than `Convert.ToString`, IMO... and provides more formatting options.

Comment: Yes, I always use List<int>. Using ArrayList would be madness! For this particular example, I'm just trying to understand the behavior of ToString() and Convert.ToString(...).